# Solved - Memory usage optimization run by f# interpreter

Tags: memory, memory-management, f#

I have a quite stupid question, but I didn't manage to answer that so far.
I am starting to write a little program in f# just to hack around a little bit with this language and a question came up to my mind: if I write a code that can be summed up like this:

```
let a = 10  
let b = a
```

how the interpreter will handle memory? Will it create a second space into the stack that contains a 10 for the variable `b` or will it just point to the same memory of the variable `a` ?

I tried to run this simple code:

```
printf "before: %A\n" (GC.GetTotalMemory false) 
let a = 10 
printf "after: %A" (GC.GetTotalMemory false) 

//output
before: 72903520L
after: 72911712L
```

and this other code:

```
printf "before: %A\n" (GC.GetTotalMemory false) 
let a = 10
let b = a 
printf "after: %A" (GC.GetTotalMemory false) 

//output
before: 73000992L
after: 73009184L
```

As the difference is quite a lot, I am not really sure about the function I chose is the right one, thus I don't know how to interpret this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has value semantics, meaning that `b` is initialized with the value of `a`, not with a reference to the location that `a` is pointing to. You can verify this by making `a` mutable and changing its value after the assignment:

```ml
let mutable a = 10
let b = a
a <- 15
printfn $"{a}"   // 15
printfn $"{b}"   // 10
```

Most of the time in F#, you can just think of these as independent values, without worrying about how they're allocated. If you're coming from a language where [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)) is common (e.g. two different names for the same mutable memory location, like C# objects), functional programming is a lot easier to think about.

Comment: Ok, pretty clear. Iha ve just one more question: is it advisable to use this "mutable approach" to save memory in a more complex application? Let's say we have two binary trees and the node in the first one refers in someway to the content of the second one. Is it a good practice to use mutable variables or is there any other approach that stick with the "no side effect" philosophy of f# that optimize the memory consumption too?

Comment: In general, no. Immutable data structures are preferred in functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about memory usage here. The memory usage that you get from the gc call is for the whole fsi process, not for your piece of code.

If your code is local, like this

```
let f() =
    let a = 10  
    let b = a
    printfn "%d" b
```

the let bindings actually don't generate any memory allocation at all. The compiler optimizes this to `printfn "%d" 10`.
There is a [nice tool](https://sharplab.io) that lets you explore what the compiler does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the toll you gave me. It will surely be useful, but the problem is the the application that I am planning to do in future needs to be optimized as far as memory is concerned and, in this case, b allocates other space in memory (following your tool indication)